# How to Add dot line to Kendo ui TreeView

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, treeview

I need to add dotted lines to detail nodes for more clarification . I know Telerik has a property named ShowLineImages which can be set to true but I think it can be only used in Webform not in MVC view.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this page? it might help :)

[Add lines between nodes](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/treeview/how-to/show-node-lines)